# How to subset a Polars DataFrame by a specific time regardless of the date?

Tags: python-polars

I have this Polars DataFrame containing electricity demand values sampled every 15 minutes.  The DataFrame, which spans across an entire month, looks like this:

```
df.head()
    shape: (5, 2)
    date    demande
    datetime[μs]    u32
    2024-01-14 00:00:00 25721
    2024-01-14 00:15:00 25558
    2024-01-14 00:30:00 25461
    2024-01-14 00:45:00 25507
    2024-01-14 01:00:00 25608
```

For analysis purposes I need to subset the DataFrame so I only keep the records made at noon.  The result would look like this (hand made):

```
sub_df.head()
    shape: (5, 2)
    date    demande
    datetime[μs]    f64
    2024-01-14 12:00:00 28078
    2024-01-15 12:00:00 30575
    2024-01-16 12:00:00 30815
    2024-01-17 12:00:00 29944
    2024-01-18 12:00:00 29850
```

Since I already could filter by demand value, like this:

```
critical_demand_df = df.filter(pl.col("demande") > 35000)
```

I tried the following analogous code:

```
sub_df = df.filter(pl.col("date").hour == 12)
```

which not surprisingly yields:

```
AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

Maybe I could resort to applying a function to the "date" column to create a new "to_keep" boolean column, and then using this column to subset the DataFrame.  But I was hoping for a lighter and cleaner solution...
Any idea?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.hour` is in the `dt` namespace: [`.dt.hour()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.dt.hour.html#polars.Expr.dt.hour)

Comment: Thanks!  This is precisely the kind of solution I was looking for.  I am new to Polars, and I guess I have a lot more to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, you can compare against the `Expression.dt.hour()`, you can additionally convert your `Datetime` column dtype to a `Time` column dtype and filter from there. Then you can compare that with either a Python `datetime.time` (see `dt_time` below) object or against a `Polars.Time` (see `pl_time` below) object.

```py
from datetime import time as dt_time, datetime, timedelta, datetime

import polars as pl
from polars import col, datetime_range, time as pl_time
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng(0)
start = datetime(2000, 1, 1)
dates = datetime_range(start, start + timedelta(days=3), interval='1H', eager=True)
df = pl.DataFrame({'date': dates, 'values': rng.random(len(dates))})

print(
    df.filter(col('date').dt.hour() == 12),
    # shape: (3, 2)
    # ┌─────────────────────┬──────────┐
    # │ date                ┆ values   │
    # │ ---                 ┆ ---      │
    # │ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64      │
    # ╞═════════════════════╪══════════╡
    # │ 2000-01-01 12:00:00 ┆ 0.857404 │
    # │ 2000-01-02 12:00:00 ┆ 0.485835 │
    # │ 2000-01-03 12:00:00 ┆ 0.404552 │
    # └─────────────────────┴──────────┘

    df.filter(col('date').dt.time() == dt_time(hour=12)),
    # shape: (3, 2)
    # ┌─────────────────────┬──────────┐
    # │ date                ┆ values   │
    # │ ---                 ┆ ---      │
    # │ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64      │
    # ╞═════════════════════╪══════════╡
    # │ 2000-01-01 12:00:00 ┆ 0.857404 │
    # │ 2000-01-02 12:00:00 ┆ 0.485835 │
    # │ 2000-01-03 12:00:00 ┆ 0.404552 │
    # └─────────────────────┴──────────┘

    df.filter(col('date').dt.time() == pl_time(hour=12)),
    # shape: (3, 2)
    # ┌─────────────────────┬──────────┐
    # │ date                ┆ values   │
    # │ ---                 ┆ ---      │
    # │ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64      │
    # ╞═════════════════════╪══════════╡
    # │ 2000-01-01 12:00:00 ┆ 0.857404 │
    # │ 2000-01-02 12:00:00 ┆ 0.485835 │
    # │ 2000-01-03 12:00:00 ┆ 0.404552 │
    # └─────────────────────┴──────────┘
    sep='\n\n',
)
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me 3 interesting solutions.  I am now moving on with my analysis using an elegant piece of code!